# Θ-notation with (n^3.2)^-n in denominator

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

For a function like `f(n) = 20n^2 + 5n + 7`, the Θ-notation clearly is `Θ(n^2)`.

But what about a more complex function where we have `(n^3.2)^-n` in the denominator?

```
f(n) = (n^2 + 2)/(1 + (n^3.2)^-n)
```

[![f(n) = (n^2 + 2)/(1 + (n^3.2)^-n)][1]][1]

Kindly explain the solution for better understanding.

Comment: Is ^ left or right-associative in this example?

Comment: @henryD Rolled back the edit. Your latest edit invalidated both existing answers. This is against the rules of this site. Please prefer to post a second, new question instead, this time with proper formatting and picture. People can then answer the new question and this question and its answers can remain here, still valid and relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It should be still O(n^2), right?

3.2^(-n) is getting infinitely close to 0 when n is increased. Then, the denominator is approximately 2 (= 1 + n^0).

Comment: Things get slightly more complex though due to the nested `(n^(3.2))^-n`. Overall, it is still true though.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

Yes, it is `Θ(n²)` as well.

---

### Why?

`f in Θ(g)` is defined as `f in O(g)` and `f in Ω(g)` at the same time.

See the definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations):

[image: Landau notation definitions]

Your method `f` is

[image: f(n) = (n^2 + 2)/(1 + ((n^3.2)^-n))]

while `g` is just `g(n) = n²`.

Now, informally, the denominator in `f` goes against `1` (`1 + 0`) since the `-n` grows extremely fast when going `n ➝ ∞`.

#### `O(n²)`

But step by step. Let us first deal with the simple direction, showing that `f in O(n²)`.

You have to show that there is a constant factor `k` and a special starting value `n₀` from which on, all `n > n₀` will yield a smaller value. So that

```
f(n) ≤ k · g(n)
```

i.e.

[image: (n^2 + 2)/(1 + ((n^3.2)^-n)) <= k * n^2]

Now, that is quite simple since you can just estimate using `≤`. The denominator is always positive and always greater `1` since the right part of the addition is always positive. Hence, it holds that you can just leave it away without making it bigger:

[image: (n^2 + 2)/(1 + ((n^3.2)^-n)) <= n^2 + 2]

and that is definitely smaller than `k · n²` if we set maybe `k = 10`, `n₀ = 10`.

#### `Ω(n²)`

The other direction is more tricky since now we have to show that `f` is actually bigger than `k · n²` despite the denominator making it smaller.

However, the tricky part in the denominator `(n^3.2)^-n` grows very fast against `0`, informally because the `-n` is much stronger than `n^3.2`. Take a look at this plot:

[image: plot (n^3.2)^-n]

You can easily show that this is monotonically decreasing and going against `0`, after the maxima at around `n ≈ 0.36`. So we can just take a higher value, such as `n₀ = 10` and then we have the denominator under good control.

Now we can start the estimation with an upper bound:

[image: (n^2 + 2)/(1 + ((n^3.2)^-n)) >= (n^2 + 2)/(1 + 10)]
[image: >= n^2/(1 + 10) = 1/11 * n^2]

So, we pick `k = 1/11`, `n₀ = 10` and are done.

#### `Θ(n²)`

Since we just showed that `f in O(n²)` and `f in Ω(n²)`, it follows that `f in Θ(n²)`.